# Ask for permission on demand

Tags: android, android-manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to ask permission programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517171/is-there-any-way-to-ask-permission-programmatically)

as my app requires the permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`
most of my users aren't happy cause on installation there's a text "paid services" (or sth) because in my app I have to make calls.

Afaik there IS a solution to NOT write permissions in the manifest, but ask for them as they are used.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Surely you just need to explain in the description of the app why you have that permission requirement.

Comment: @rawkode: u were the first one, so if you want the kudos just make a post with that link instead of a comment ;) ...

Comment: With the latest version of an Android, i.e. Android M the Runtime App Permissions are supported. Too late, but it is there now.

Comment: Now it is possible to get the permission from user dynamically

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change permissions of existing app, but you may create two different apps, one with `CALL_PHONE` permission, and another one without it. And let the people decide which one they want to install.

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm one of the developers who would like to see some hybrid permission system in place, there is no solution as of today, at least according to the docs.

> Android has **no mechanism for granting permissions dynamically** (at run-time) because it complicates the user experience to the detriment of security.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html)