# Is it possible to specify the <uses-permission> programatically?

Tags: android, google-maps

IS there any way to specify the  in programmatically means in activity l?
Because in google play,When user trying to install the application, it says the android application is not compatible with your kindle fire tablet device.

In My application ,we are using the map v2 version it requires OpenGL ES version 2. 
Can we develop the application as like this ,Suppose if the device not support the map v2 version can we go for the map v1?

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to ask permission programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517171/is-there-any-way-to-ask-permission-programmatically)

Comment: Is OpenGL version included in android version or device specification?

Comment: Can we develop the application as like this ,Suppose if the device not support the map v2 version can we go for the map v1?

Comment: Read about backward compatibility. However Maps V2 should work on most Android devices.

Answer (score 3):

```
Big No
```

`<uses-permission>`:

*Requests a permission that the application must be granted in order for it to operate correctly. Permissions are granted by the user when the application is installed, not while it's running.*

Check:

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

[Security Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)

Answer (score 1):

**No. The user needs to be informed about the permissions while installing the application. Askling them at runtime would be a security risk.**

Applications statically declare the permissions they require, and the Android system prompts the user for consent at the time the application is installed. Android has no mechanism for granting permissions dynamically (at run-time) because it complicates the user experience to the detriment of security.

Check [Android Developer site - Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give the permission at run time. Permission must be granted at the time of installing the application.

You’re using the Google Maps library to bring maps to your Android application. You can’t use this library (either map v1 version & map v2 version) on the Kindle Fire. Because the Kindle Fire isn’t a “true” Android device (it doesn’t use the official Google Android source code but instead uses its custom version), it doesn’t have access to any of the closed-source Google services that you might already be using.

The Android-based Kindle can run apps with few or no modifications. It has no access to the Google Play Store, though, which means that if you want Kindle Fire users to be able to download your application, you have to pub- lish your app to the Amazon Appstore for Android.

Comment: Sinu Varghese thanks for valueable informtation.SUppose my android application support the the Kindle Fire device without map functionality and work remaining existing features of my application.Is is possible to do that.If possible how ? Thanx in adv.