# Clear allowed permissions on Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

How to clear all allowed permissions on Android Marshmallow? This need for developing and testing.

I know, that I can do it manually, but I want to do this in programmatically way.

Comment: I am not sure that there is an option for all permissions. Individually, use `adb shell pm revoke`, such as `adb shell pm revoke com.commonsware.android.perm.tutorial android.permission.CAMERA`. You could always write a Gradle task or other script that examines the merged manifest/`aapt dump badging` output, finds the `dangerous` permissions, and then runs `adb shell pm revoke` for each.

Comment: Thank you. Command 
adb shell pm revoke com.application android.permission.CAMERA 
is very useful.

But I cannot execute comandLine in the gradle :( Task is working, but commandLine with that args wont to work
commandLine 'adb',  'shell',  'pm',  'revoke',  'com.application', 'android.permission.CAMERA'

I tried to set full path to adb, but that not work too.

Otherwise, very Thank you for this command. I executed it in the Android Sudio terminal and it that, what I needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug Android 6.0 permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512880/how-to-debug-android-6-0-permissions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found answer :-)

Command

```
adb shell pm reset-permissions
```

Comment: adb shell pm reset-permissions package_name would clear only specific app permissions