# Force android to ask for run time permission every time regardless of prior acceptance

Tags: android

Whenever you accept a runtime permission Android remembers it for about 24 hours I think. However when testing this a big annoyance especially when I have different parts of the app that need the same permission. I want to see if the app works correctly if the user hasn't already accepted the runtime permission but I only have two devices to work with so once I've accepted I can't really see. Is there a way to forget accepted run time permissions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug/reset Android 6.0 permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512880/how-to-debug-reset-android-6-0-permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever you accept a runtime permission Android remembers it for about 24 hours I think

No, it lasts until revoked, either by the user revoking the permission in Settings, by the user clearing data in Settings, or by the user uninstalling the app.

> Is there a way to forget accepted run time permissions?

You can revoke the permission from the Settings app (Settings > Apps > (your app) > Permissions).