# Turn off app permissions programmatically

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

How can I deny certain app permissions programatically or deny all app permissions at once in marshmallow?

I do not want to revoke them, I just want to turn them off from my app, not through app settings. I know I can use Intent to open app settings and change them that way. That's not an option for me.

Thanks!

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535088/android-m-programmatically-revoke-permissions

Comment: Thanks! I guess there is not an option right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android M: Programmatically revoke permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535088/android-m-programmatically-revoke-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

It is not posible. this contradicts the whole idea of permission, maybe you will find a way to do it, it will be corrected in the next secyrty patch.