# How to get if an app requests a permission?

Tags: java, android, permissions, manifest

Good morning

I was searching for a way to know if an app, given the package name, requests a certain permission and if that permission is granted (via settings). I was looking for something like that:

```
if(//com.package.name requests Manifest.permission.camera and that permission is granted)
{//do something}
```

I have already read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535088/android-m-programmatically-revoke-permissions but it doesn't find a way to know if an app is actually requesting a certain permission and if it's granted.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the following code in your activity:

I created `StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions = new StringBuffer();` to append all the apps and permisssions info.

It's working fine. I tested it already. If you have any issues, please let me know.

```
StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions = new StringBuffer();
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
    Log.d("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    appNameAndPermissions.append(packageInfo.packageName+"*******:\n");

    //Get Permissions
    String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
    if(requestedPermissions != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
            appNameAndPermissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");
        }
    appNameAndPermissions.append("\n");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Use the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>`

**Source** and more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5385957/4205927)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test it ASAP and give feedback!